# Puzzled with file descriptor in Bash (ffmpeg video capture)

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, file-descriptor

I am trying to use file descriptors in Bash and found a problem I cannot solve.
I have to read a video stream coming from the standard output of a command executed in a `coproc`. This piece of code works as expected :

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <(exec cat <&${COPROC[0]}) \
    -c:v $ENCODE_VIDEO_FORMAT_LOSSLESS $ENCODE_VIDEO_OPTIONS_LOSSLESS \
    -c:a copy \
    -progress /dev/fd/1 \
    "${capfile}"
```

But the `cat` process is not really useful since `ffmpeg -i pipe:<file descriptor>` seems to do the same. So I tried the following code which fails with `pipe:63: Bad file descriptor`
 error.

```
ffmpeg \
    -i pipe:"${COPROC[0]}" \
    -c:v $ENCODE_VIDEO_FORMAT_LOSSLESS $ENCODE_VIDEO_OPTIONS_LOSSLESS \
    -c:a copy \
    -progress /dev/fd/1 \
    "${capfile}"
```

The actual script is something a bit complicated but here is a minimal testing code for this issue :

```
#!/bin/bash
#

ENCODE_VIDEO_FORMAT_LOSSLESS=ffv1
ENCODE_VIDEO_OPTIONS_LOSSLESS="-level 3 -threads 7 -coder 1 -context 1 -g 1 -slices 30 -slicecrc 1"

capfile=capure.mkv

coproc ffmpeg  -i file:'Camomille.mkv' -c:v copy -c:a copy -f matroska pipe:1

capture_fd=${COPROC[0]}
echo "hk_capture_pid=${COPROC_PID}"

ffmpeg \
    -i pipe:${COPROC[0]} \
    -c:v $ENCODE_VIDEO_FORMAT_LOSSLESS $ENCODE_VIDEO_OPTIONS_LOSSLESS \
    -c:a copy \
    -progress /dev/fd/1 \
    "${capfile}"
```

This is the output of the second `ffmpeg` command :

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1build2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-4ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1build2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
pipe:63: Bad file descriptor
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe                                                                                       
Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Broken pipe                                                                                    
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      48kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=10051.1kbits/s speed=3.44x    
video:86kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

This one fails and if you replace `-i pipe:${COPROC[0]}` by `-i <(exec cat <&${COPROC[0]})` a capture.mkv file is created.

I run ubuntu eoan and bash version is : `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. I upgraded several times since I started with this issue, so it wouldn't be related too much to bash and ffmpeg versions.

If someone can point me to what I do wrong with bash file descriptors I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file descriptor ${COPROC[0]} is valid only for the shell, not for ffmpeg.

So what you need is :

```
ffmpeg \
    -i pipe:0 \
    -c:v $ENCODE_VIDEO_FORMAT_LOSSLESS $ENCODE_VIDEO_OPTIONS_LOSSLESS \
    -c:a copy \
    -progress /dev/fd/1 \
    "${capfile}" <&${COPROC[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried that but without the `-i pipe:0` part because I thought that ffmpeg would read from its stdin but apparently not.
Well this `pipe:` "protocol" is not very usefull since it doesn't do more than the standard `-i -` synthax.